# how to read a specific line from a text file c++

Tags: c++, fstream

If I have a text file like this:
a
b
c
d

How can I read the nth line without a counting loop so if the line number is 3 I can get the letter c.

Comment: Your example only contains 1 line.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to know the offset (in bytes) where the third line begins.

You can build an 'index' for this file (iterate through the file once and store position where each line begins). Or maybe the offset can be calculated/guessed if you know that all lines have the same length.

Without this prior knowledge, you can not read a line with arbitrary number from a file.

Comment: Yes all the lines are the same length (there are about 1,5 mil and more lines) so I think its more efficient to calculate the offset. But how do I calculate it and then how can I use the offset the read the line.

Comment: The offset would be n*(length of line, including end-of-line character(s)). Set the position in the file to this offset using `fseek` or `seek` (depending on how you work with the file), and then read.

Answer (score 0):

Here, n begins at 0

```
string line;
for (streamsize i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    if (! getline(myfile, line))
    {
        // some issue occured, probably not enough lines
    }
}

// line variable now contains line n
```